# SQL MIN() strange value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, floating-point

I'm working on a small webshop and I'm trying to get the lowest price for a product (photos).

So I check to see what the lowest added price is (photos can be ordered in different sizes):

```
SELECT 
  MIN(price) as price 
FROM 
  rm_prices 
WHERE 
  photo_id = '47' AND 
  price != '0'
```

This returns the lowest value found for this product.

When I check my db, I see that the lowest value is 1256.3.
When I print my result, the number give is 1256.30004882813.
The value is set as a FLOAT.

Why is the result 1256.30004882813 and not 1256.3?

Comment: Check this out, it's very important to know how FLOATing point arithmetic really works, as it WILL trip you up if you just assume it's always 'perfectly accurate'...  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the [real number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) 1256.3 cannot be represented precisely in [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

You should be using a [fixed-point datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) for monetary data. Quoting from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> The `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` types store exact numeric data values.
>   These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision,
>   for example with monetary data.

Answer (score 6):

It's a side effect of FLOAT column type, you can try to store your prices in a DECIMAL data type, see the mysql manual for more info about it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: It's almost certainly this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`1256.3` does not have an exact representation in floating-point arithmetic; for that reason it is usually better to store sums of money as `INTEGER` or `DECIMAL` data types.

More information may be found [here](http://www.stemkoski.com/how-to-properly-store-currencymoney-in-mysql/).